# Stripe payment select styling

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, stripe-payments

I'm trying to style the stripe dropdown select to match bootstrap's select. here is my html

```
<form id="payment-form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div>
      <label for="bank-element">
        Bank
      </label>
      <div id="bank-element">
        <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button id="button" data-secret="<?= $intent->client_secret ?>">
    Submit Payment
  </button>

  <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
  <div id="error-message" role="alert"></div>
</form>
```

in my js file i have this

```
var style = {
    base: {
        'padding': "10px 12px",
        'color': '#495057',
        'fontFamily': 'apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif',
        'border-color': '#80BDFF',
        'outline':'0',
        'box-shadow': '0 0 0 .2rem rgba(0,123,255,.25)',
        'transition': 'border-color .15s ease-in-out, box-shadow .15s ease-in-out'
      },
      invalid: {
        color: "#fa755a"
      }
};

var Bank = elements.create(
    'Bank',
    {style: style, accountHolderType: 'individual'}
  );
```

`id="bank-element"` is there the dropdown select is. Anyone know how to do this? or that I'm missing. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Great question, but unfortunately you're limited to the style options listed here:
https://stripe.com/docs/js/appendix/style

This means that you won't be able to set: `border-color`, `transition`, `border-color`, or `outline` on the element itself. You can apply a border & animations to the container div, but you won't be able to set up the animation transition on anything inside the Element.